# javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am trying to run example from official spring batch samples. Now I am stuck on [remote chunking example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotechunking)

I created separated project to start it:

[image]

**MasterApplication:**

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class MasterApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MasterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**MasterConfiguration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableBatchIntegration
@EnableIntegration
@PropertySource("classpath:remote-chunking.properties")
public class MasterConfiguration {

    @Value("${broker.url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private RemoteChunkingMasterStepBuilderFactory masterStepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(this.brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    /*
     * Configure outbound flow (requests going to workers)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(requests())
                .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("requests"))
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure inbound flow (replies coming from workers)
     */
    @Bean
    public QueueChannel replies() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("replies"))
                .channel(replies())
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure master step components
     */
    @Bean
    public ListItemReader<Integer> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskletStep masterStep() {
        return this.masterStepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(3)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .outputChannel(requests())
                .inputChannel(replies())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job remoteChunkingJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("remoteChunkingJob")
                .start(masterStep())
                .build();
    }

}
```

**remote-chunking.properties:**

```
broker.url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/testdb?user=XXX&password=XXXX
```

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'remote-batch-processing'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-activemq'
    compile "org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker"
    compile "org.apache.activemq:activemq-client"

    compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms"


    compile("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-integration:4.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    //to fix exception o startup
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.2.Final')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Now I am trying to start `MasterApplication` and I seee following in logs:

```
2019-08-13 16:28:54.639 ERROR 25316 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step masterStep in job remoteChunkingJob

org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Retry exhausted after last attempt in recovery path, but exception is not skippable.; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [outboundFlow.jms:outbound-channel-adapter#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=ChunkRequest: jobId=196, sequence=0, contribution=[StepContribution: read=0, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING], item count=3, headers={id=2caf7c04-2572-4422-290c-f957d400ec27, timestamp=1565702933610}]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$5.recover(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:413) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:512) ~[spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:351) ~[spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211) ~[spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:217) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.write(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:212) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:399) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:206) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:180) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:167) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:162) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at my.batch.experiments.master.MasterApplication.main(MasterApplication.java:41) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [outboundFlow.jms:outbound-channel-adapter#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:189) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:186) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:99) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.write(ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.java:107) ~[spring-batch-integration-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:188) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:154) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$3.doWithRetry(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:336) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:691) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler.send(JmsSendingMessageHandler.java:216) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(JmsSendingMessageHandler.java:184) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:374) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.access$100(JmsTemplate.java:89) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$JmsTemplateResourceFactory.createConnection(JmsTemplate.java:1180) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalSession(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:325) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:491) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:525) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doStart(TcpTransport.java:488) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.start(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:169) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.start(InactivityMonitor.java:52) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:72) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:354) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar:5.15.9]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: How is your broker configured?

Comment: I expect it should be run as embedded server. It is everything I have

Comment: `broker.url=tcp://localhost:61616` your application is configured to listen to a broker on port 61616. Apparently there is none running, that's why you got the error.

Comment: You can download the broker [here](https://activemq.apache.org/) and start it with the command `activemq start`.

Comment: @T A  I want embedded variant. I will try to separate my application into 2 different apps

Comment: @T A, Because of ActiveMQConnectionFactory I need use broker.url